# Difference between []Foo(nil) and []Foo{} in Go

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I'm new to Go and would like to know the difference between `[]Foo(nil)` and `[]Foo{}`.

(I'm using this in my tests, where I want to specify that when my function errors, it should return `nil, err`. The go linter complains when I use `nil` or `[]Foo{}`, but works when I use `[]Foo(nil)`.)

### What I've tried

I had a look at the Go docs and on SO and found Struct stuff about `Foo{}` but not `[]Foo(nil)`.

When I use `[]Foo{}`, the test failure outputs:

```
expected: []Foo{}
actual  : []Foo(nil)
```

Fmt outputs for `[]Foo(nil)` and `[]Foo{}` are the same:

```
fmt.Println([]Foo(nil)) // []
fmt.Println([]Foo(){}) // []
fmt.Printf([]Foo(nil)) // []Foo
fmt.Printf([]Foo(){}) // []Foo
```

I noticed that if I write just `Foo(nil)` (without the `[]`) then the linter complains about `cannot convert nil to type Foo`.

So my only guess is that `[]Foo(nil)` invokes some type coercion. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If the distinction between a nil slice and empty slice is not important in your tests, then test with `len(s) == 0`. This expression evaluates to true for both nil slices and empty slices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `[]Foo(nil)` is a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). It converts the untyped nil to a nil slice of type `[]Foo`.

The expression `[]Foo{}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) that returns a empty slice. It's empty because no elements are listed between the `{}`.

This might help explain the difference:

```
fmt.Println([]Foo(nil) == nil) // prints true
fmt.Println([]Foo{} == nil)    // prints false
```

A nil slice does not have a backing array.  An empty slice has a backing array with length 0.

What's confusing is that the fmt package can output the same data for empty slices and nil slices.

If the distinction between a nil slice and empty slice is not important in your tests, then test with `len(s) == 0`.  This expression evaluates to true for both nil slices and empty slices.